# Alternatives à « est-ce que » ?

Tags: oral, questions

Durant mes études, j'ai beaucoup utilisé l'expression *est-ce que* pour poser des questions. Mais récemment j'ai parlé avec une amie qui est au Québec et qui étudie aussi le français, et je lui ai posé la question : « L'accent est-il un problème pour toi ? ».

J'ai voulu dire « Est-ce que l'accent québecois est difficile à comprendre pour toi ? » (parce que nous avons étudié le français seulement en classe, pas dans le monde réel).
J'ai vu la forme interrogative *est-il* et j'ai voulu l'utiliser. Mais est-ce que mon usage est correct ?

Ca m'ennuie d'utiliser *est-ce que* tout le temps, et je voudrais utiliser les autres formes. Est-ce qu'on peut m'aider et me renseigner sur les autres formes interrogatives ?

Comment: Peut-être une réponse [ici](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2848/est-ce-que-for-requests) et [ici](http://www.lepointdufle.net/interrogation.htm)

Answer (score 10):

Oui, c'est correct.

Si ça vous embête de rajouter "est-ce que" à chaque fois, vous pouvez faire comme 90% des français quand ils parlent et dire simplement:

> L'accent est un problème pour toi?

C'est exactement comme la phrase affirmative, mais avec un ton interrogatif.

D'autre part, il serait plus naturel de dire:

> L'accent te pose problème?

ou si vous voulez insister sur "accent":

> C'est l'accent qui te pose problème?

ou

> C'est un problème pour toi, l'accent?

Comment: J'aurais même dit "*C'est un problème pour toi, l'accent ?*"

Comment: Bonne idée, j'ai édité.

Comment: ne dit on pas "l'accent te pose-t-il problème ?" plutôt ?

Comment: Grammaticalement correct, mais plutôt dans un écrit formel qu'à l'oral, non?

Comment: @oli Bien d'accord. Cette formulation, avec une inversion en milieu, me semble particulièrement peu naturelle à l'oral.