# How best to say, "What are we going to do?"

Tags: sens, expressions

I see several translations for the English expression, “What are we going to do?”

> 1. Qu'est-ce qu'on va faire ?
> 2. Qu'est-ce que nous allons faire ? (more polite than "Qu'est-ce qu'on va faire?" ?)
> 3. Qu'allons-nous faire ?
> 4. Que va-t-on faire ?

Can someone explain the difference between them? In other words, is one more formal, or more polite, or more common in daily use, or whatever.
How is using “on va” different from “nous allons”; and how is "Qu'est-ce qu’” different from reversing the subject-object position.
What would you use in normal daily conversation (as opposed to a more formal written form)?

Comment: You probably mean subject/ **verb** inversion.   *On* vs *nous* : http://french.stackexchange.com/q/13910/358 ; *Est-ce que* vs *subject* / *verb inversion*: http://french.stackexchange.com/q/2848/358.

Answer (score 1):

En employant "nous", ça rend la phrase plus formelle et polie. Pour parler aux autres, à moins que vous ne parliez pas à quelqu'un qui vous oblige d'employer ce pronom personnel, n'importe lequel irait. C'est quand vous écrivez que vous devez faire plus attention auquel vous utilisez.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT :** As @Laure let me know in the comments, the following is only a personal experience, and it may differ.

**Most used orally :** Qu'est-ce qu'on va faire ?

**More formal :** Qu'allons-nous faire ?

"Que va-t-on faire ?" and "Qu'est-ce que nous allons faire ?" are almost never used (in my experience), or at least sound strange to me, though they are grammatically correct.

**Here is the detailed explanation in French:**

Je n'entends jamais personne prononcer ces deux dernières phrases. Pour moi, la raison est que l'inversion "Que va-t-on faire" par opposition à "Qu'est-ce qu'on va faire" est plus soutenue. De même, l'utilisation du "nous" est également plus soutenue. Par conséquent, les formulations qui reviennent (pour ce que je vois) le plus souvent sont soit "Qu'est-ce qu'on va faire" pour une utilisation orale et quotidienne, ou "Qu'allons-nous faire" pour une utilisation plus soutenue et écrite. Les deux autres phrases sont une sorte de mélange de deux niveau de langage qui me paraissent très étranges. Mais gardez à l'esprit que certaines phrases peuvent différer selon les régions de France ou même selon les personnes.

Comment: @Random I never use *Qu'est-ce qu'on va faire ?*,  I  always say *Que va-t-on faire ? I might occasionally use *Qu'est-ce que nous allons faire ?*.

Comment: @Laure I hope you don't mind if I speak French? Je suis plus à l'aise. Je n'ai effectivement pas de données statistiques, et je parle de mon expérience personnelle. Je n'entends réellement jamais personne prononcer ces phrases. Pour moi, la raison est que l'inversion "Que va-t-on faire" par opposition à "Qu'est-ce qu'on va faire" est plus soutenue. De même, l'utilisation du nous est également plus soutenue que celle du "on". Par conséquent, les formulations qui reviennent (pour ce que je vois) le plus souvent sont soit "Qu'est-ce qu'on va faire" pour une utilisation orale et quotidienne (1/2)

Comment: ou "Qu'allons-nous faire" pour une utilisation plus soutenue et écrite. Les deux autres phrases sont une sorte de mélange de deux niveau de langage qui me paraissent très étranges. Je peux cependant concevoir que l'utilisation de certaines phrases diffère selon les régions de France (je suppose que vous êtes Française ?), et je n'aurais peut-être pas dû affirmer qu'elles n'étaient presque jamais utilisées. (2/2)

Comment: Les commentaires sont là pour aider à améliorer les questions. Si vous voulez revenir sur une formulation il est toujours possible de l'éditer. C'est l'esprit même de Stack Exchange ! Au fait bienvenue sur French Language.

Comment: @Laure C'est fait, j'ai nuancé mes propos. Mais j’admets être assez surpris que ces phrases soient utilisées car je ne les ai presque jamais entendues. Autant pour moi.

Comment: @Random Je l'aurais bien fait mais je suis moins à l'aise en anglais, alors pour traduire ça correctement... ^^'

Comment: @Random C'est bon, et je garde les commentaires tout de même. En tout cas merci à vous deux pour avoir améliorer ma réponse, je suis nouveau sur stackexchange :)

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things to know:

1. "Nous" is more formal than "on", and is mostly used on written texts (serious ones, like news papers, books...)
2. "Qu'est-ce que" is the opposite of "nous" (about style), it can't be used on formal language, and rarely used on written texts, but will be commonly used on oral conversations.

You won't use "qu'est-ce que" with "nous" (your sentence 2), whereas you can use "on" with a subject-verb inversion (your sentence 4). All this is a matter of style.

Your sentence 3 is the more polite (for books, newspapers etc...), *sentence 1* is the more familiar (for daily conversations), and *sentence 4* is between *1* and *3* (let's say for a conversation with your boss...).